# bei jemandem einen Stein im Brett haben

Tags: idiom

I have been undertaking a beginner's class in German. I have been picking up some idiomatic phrases as I go along and have comes across the following German construction:

> bei jemandem einen Stein im Brett haben

Which I understand in English to mean:

> to be in somebody's good books

I wanted to say:

> I am in Karl’s good books.

And have come up with:

> Ich habe bei Karl einen Stein im Brett.

Is this the correct way of using this construction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this use is absolutely correct.

### Trivia

Taken from wiktionary.org

> Die Redewendung kommt schon in der Sprichwörtersammlung des Johannes Agricola von 1529 vor und geht auf ein im Mittelalter beliebtes Brettspiel namens Puff [wo das Spiel gespielt wurde] oder Tricktrack zurück. Wer dort einen „Bund“ (zwei Steine, die nebeneinander stehen) an einer Stelle im Brett hat, über die ein anderer mit seinen Steinen noch hinübermuss, und selbst bereits einen seiner Steine jenseits des „Bundes“ platzieren konnte, hat schon halb gewonnen.

Die positive Bedeutung kann nur losgelöst von dem Spiel betrachtet werden: Der "Stein im Brett" ist etwas durchaus Positives für den Spieler selbst.

Comment: International ist Puff übrigens als Backgammon bekannt.